# Why is TabBarView taking the extra space?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I've been playing around with Flutter for a few days, trying to build a simple app with a VideoPlayer on the first half of the screen (dynamic size) and a ListView on the bottom half. I want the top half to be as small as possible, but TabBarView (the yellow background portion) is taking that extra space.

[image]

I tried wrapping TabBarView with an Expanded, flexible, sizedbox, etc. None of them worked. I pinpointed the problem to this exact Widget, because if I remove it, leaving just the VideoPlayer widget, it works!

[image]

Everything is wrapped in a Scaffold's body:

```
Column(mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, children: [
        Flexible(
          fit: FlexFit.loose,
          child: VideoList(),
        ),
        Expanded(child: RepetitionsList()),
      ]),
```

VideoList:

```
 Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          color: Colors.redAccent,
          height: 35,
          child: TabBar(
            controller: _controller,
            tabs: [
              Tab(
                child: Text("Video 1"),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
        Flexible(
            fit: FlexFit.loose,
            child: Container(
                color: Colors.yellow,
                child: TabBarView(
                    controller: _controller, children: [VideoPlayer()]))),
      ],
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

1). Use `flexfit.tight` so that it stick with its position and size irrespective of the content on remaining portion of screen.

2). I suggest you to rather than hardcoding height of container make it flexible to all screen sizes by using `MediaQuery.of(context).size.height` by using this if you want to make videoScreen half of screen size than simply divide Screensize by 2 like `MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/2`

3). Maybe this solution helps you i.e try giving flex values and because when you are using expanded or flexible it divides you screensize eg if there are two expanded or flexible widgets both take 50% of your screen.

```
Column(mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, children: [
    Flexible(
      flex: 1,
      fit: FlexFit.loose,
      child: VideoList(),
    ),
    Expanded(flex: 2,child: RepetitionsList()),
  ]),
```

Comment: Already tried that, didn't work. Thank you.

Comment: Answer to your edit: well, actually, I want the VideoPlayer (wrapped with the TabBarView) to take as little space as it needs.

Comment: there is also a code portion mentioned in next edit It hope this helps

Comment: That causes a bottom overflow by 12 pixels on the VideoList widget. Shouldn't there be a way to tell TabBarView, "hey, take as little space as you can"?

Comment: yes remove the flexible for first widget and give that widget height of screen you wanted and wrap second widget with expanded, by doing this second widget will take remaining space, All you have to do is remove flexible or expanded for VideoList. Give VideoList widget specific height you want and wrap RepetitionList Widget with expanded and dont give flex so it will occupy remaining space

Comment: You can also increase decrease the value of flex to fit your content on screen. Flex is basically you are describing percentage or weightage of expanded if there are two expanded widgets if you give 1,1 flex respectively it means both share 50% 50% space respectively if you give 1,3 means one widget use 25% and other widget use 75% space

Comment: But I want VideoList to have dynamic size, the minimum it needs. The VideoPlayer should have an intrinsic height, so everything should build up from there, right?

Comment: your video player would have dynamic size by using expanded flex or `MediaQuery`  you just have to specify how much portion of screen do you need